# Redirects in vue router v4

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I'm migrating from `Vue Router v3` to `Vue Router v4` and bumped into an unexpected problem that breaks quite a lot of logic in my app - maybe someone faced it and knows a good solution.

In `Vue Router v3` I was relying on a "chained redirect" to set the default location where each child determines where and how to redirect.

For example:

`/` -> `/1` -> `/1/2` -> `/1/2/3`

No matter where user starts in this chain, their default starting position would be `/1/2/3` (and this is my target behaviour)

```
[

        {
            path: '/',
            redirect: '/1',
        },
        {
            path: '/1',
            component: DashboardListPage,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    redirect: '2',
                },
                {
                    path: '2',
                    component: DashboardMainPage,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: '',
                            redirect: '3'
                        },
                        {
                            path: '3',
                            component: DashboardListPage,
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
```

This used to work with `Vue Router v3` but seems to no longer with `Vue Router v4`

In `Vue Router v4` it just does the following (not what I need):

- `/` -> `/2` (no idea why `/2`)
- `/1` -> `/2`
- `/1/2` -> `/3`

Again in all cases I'd expect it to redirect to `/1/2/3`

Is there any setting in the `Vue Router v4` that I'm missing?
Any hint on how to achieve that redirection behaviour is much appreciated.

Comment: Try to make routes unambiguous and use `name` instead of paths.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks man, that did the trick. If you can post it as an answer I'll accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per reply on the similar question from the router member on [github](https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/2014#issuecomment-1759871942):

> This change was indeed intended: relatives paths are always resolved
> based on the current location to avoid inconsistencies to how Relative
> URLs work. In your case, the first redirect is absolute, it works, the
> second one is relative, it resolves to a route you don't have and then
> it stops. I recommend you to do one of these:
>
> 1. use absolute paths in redirects
> 2. use named routes for a deterministic
>    route location
> 3. remove the links in your application that are using any
>    of the routes that have a redirect
>
> This has been overlooked in the migration guide.

Answer (score 0):

In Vue Router 4 I found the following router path pattern solves nested redirection

```
const routes = [
   {
     path: '/',
     redirect: '/a'
   },
   {
   path: '/a',
   component: ParentView,
   children: [
     {
      path: '',
      redirect: '/a/b'
    },
    {
      path: 'b',
      component: ChildView,
      children: [
       {
         path: '',
         redirect: '/a/b/c'
       },
       {
         path: 'c',
         component: GrandChildView
       }
     ]
  }
]
```

}
]

Comment: In Vue router 3.x it's working as you specified but with Vue router 4.x redirection need absolute path instead of relevant path.

Comment: That works, thanks! This assumes that the child know the parent's path thought. I was using the initial approach for modularity and would like to keep each modulle "parent unaware" is possible. And redirection by name as mentioned by Estus Flask seems to do the job here too. As a bonus, redirect by name also preserves params if present in url.